# IPython and file encoding

Tags: python, encoding, ipython

I have this file called `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#`foo`

print 'hello'
```

Now, if I execute the file via $python$, I get the following error:

```
$ python main.py 
  File "main.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file main.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

While if I use "ipython" (IPython 5.1.0), all is fine:

```
$ ipython main.py 
hello
```

Does IPython have a different standard file-encoding?

Comment: you could try to get rid of the backquotes on the comment of line 2.

Comment: I know that the problem is there. My question was about the different behavior of IPython

Comment: Or you could add an explicit `-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` or whatever, to support both Python and IPython, with weird characters in your file or without. (Of course, if your editor writes some other encoding than UTF-8, you have to put that instead; of switch to an editor which supports UTF-8, which is probably the sane choice going forward.)

Comment: Ok it's fine, but I do not understand why IPython behaves differently than `python`.

Comment: the `site.py` config may contain a different default encoding.

Comment: Look at `sys.stdin.encoding` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.  https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.utils.encoding.html may also applly.